# how to detect webcam in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have done one webcam project which will supports view live webcam images.I am using "ENTER USB 2.0" locally its working fine..when i upload it to the webserver and test with client browser..Its not working..its getting errors as "No devices Found"..is there any server settings to detect the webcams?..

How can we detect any type of webcams in asp.net..?Or is there any activeX plug-ins for detecting the webcam on client browsers..

Its very important to me..please share with me..if you have any ideas?

thanks in advance..

Comment: Use jpegcam: code.google.com/p/jpegcam/

Answer (score 1):

I used [jpegcam](http://code.google.com/p/jpegcam/) once to upload photo from webcam. Hope this helps. Basic code is like (using [jquery](http://jquery.com/)):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<path to webcam.js (inside jpegcam)>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        webcam.set_swf_url('path to webcam.swf(inside jpegcam)');
        webcam.set_api_url(document.URL);
        webcam.set_quality(90); // JPEG quality (1 - 100)
        webcam.set_shutter_sound(false);


    $("#imgWrapper").css({ height: "262px",
        width: "215px",
        border: "solid 1px #aaa"
    });

    var pb = $("#tp");
    pb.addClass("spbtn");

    pb.click(function () {
        $("#fc").html(webcam.get_html(215, 262));
        viewCam(true);
    });
});

function viewCam(show) {
    if (show) {
        $("#sc").hide();
        $("#iUploadFrame").fadeIn();
    }
    else {
        $("#iUploadFrame").hide();
        $("#sc").fadeIn();
    }
}

function camReset() {
    webcam.reset();
    setCamInstruction("Adjust, snap, then upload", "#666");
}

function setCamInstruction(msg, c) {
    $("#upStatus").html(msg).css("color", c);
}

function handleUpload() {
    var gi = $("#ghimg");
    gi.css("visibility", "visible")
    webcam.upload(document.URL, function () {
        gi.css("visibility", "hidden")
        setCamInstruction("Upload complete!", "green");
    });
}
</script>
```

html:

```
<div id="sc" style="width: 218px">
        <div id="imgWrapper">
            <img src="<path to a placeholder image>" alt="no photo" id="imgPhoto"
                runat="server" height="262" width="215" />
        </div>
    <br />
    <div style="text-align: center">
        <span id="tp">Open Webcam</span>
    </div>
    <br />
</div>
<div id="iUploadFrame" style="display: none;">
    <div id="fc">
        -- Cam Content --
    </div>
    <div id="upStatus" style="padding: 5px 0; color: #666;">
        Adjust, snap, then upload</div>
    <input type="button" value="Snap" onclick="webcam.freeze()" />
    <input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="camReset();" />
    <input type="button" value="Upload" onclick="handleUpload()" />
    <div class="progress_beside_inline" id="ghimg">
    </div>
</div>
```